# computed column or indexed view?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a column part # that can contain many non-alphanumeric characters.  I frequently need to compare part #'s from customers or vendors to our data.  I've been doing this successfully with a user-defined function that returns only alpha-Numeric.  I improved performance by creating a computed column called stripPartNum on an indexed view.  I would like to move this computed column to the table.

I cannot create the computed column as persisted so I can create an index on the column.
Error:
Computed column 'stripPartNum' in table 'inventory' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

I created a new user-defined function not using patIndex, but still have the same problem.
Here is the function:

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[anOnly]
(
@string VARCHAR(900)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(900)

AS
BEGIN

Declare @pos int,@newString varchar(1000),@charAt char(1)
Set @pos = 0
Set @newString = ''

while @pos <= len(@string)
    begin
    Set @charAt = substring(@string,@pos,1)
    if @charAt not like '[^0-9A-Za-z]'
        Set @newString = @newString + @charAt
    Set @pos = @pos + 1
    end

return @newString
END
```

Why am I able to create an index on the computed column in the view but not on the table?  Is there a solution I am overlooking?

Comment: Maybe a better question is why is this user-defined function non-deterministic?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just found the answer.  My function must be schema bound.